# Cross-domain requests using PhoneGap and jQuery doesn't work

Tags: jquery, ajax, cordova, cross-domain

I'm creating a PhoneGap app for Android. To get data from the (remote) server I make a REST call using jQuery's $.ajax() function. There are a few things you must know:

- Type of the call must be POST
- The server expects JSON data(at least username and password)
- The server sends back JSON data

The code:

```
function makeCall(){
    var url = "http://remote/server/rest/call";

    var jsonData ='{"username":"'+$('#username').val()+'","password":"'+$('#password').val()+'"}';

    $.ajax({
            headers: {"Content-Type":"application/json; charset=UTF-8"},
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: jsonData,
            dataType: "json",
            success: succesFunction,
            error: errorFunction
    });
}
```

But, this doesn't work. When I use Firebug to see the servers response, there is nothing. With TcpTrace I can see the headers of the request. Instead of an expected POST method, there is an OPTIONS method, with some strange headers added.

```
OPTIONS /remote/server/rest/call HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8081
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: nl,en-us;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Origin: null
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

I know it has something to do with doing cross-domain requests, but I don't know how to solve the problem. I tried a few things to fix it, but with no result:

- Use 'jsonp' in stead of 'json'
- Try to use [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/)

The problem has also something to do with same origin policy, but this does not apply to the file:// protocol PhoneGap is using to load a local html file.

In my AndroidManifest.xml file, the option

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

is set.

I'm trying to fix this for 2 days now, but no result till now. Is this even possible to do? Do you have any tips for me so I can move on?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved the problem by myself. The problem is located in the url, where I have to add a domain. I changed

`var url = "http://remote/server/rest/call";`

to

`var url = "http://remote.mydomain.com/server/rest/call";`

and it works!

I assumed the first url should work because it works on an iphone app with exact the same url and settings. It has also something to do with a double firewall(Windows and ESET firewall) where I shut down the Windows firewall.

Anyway, thanks for your answers!

Comment: your problem might be fixed but this is not the answer what solves the cross-domain-request issue

Answer (score 10):

you need to whitelist your external domains. just go to your phonegap / cordova plist file in xcode and add a new entry, have it's value be * and you can access any website out there.

also know that this WILL NOT WORK IN A BROWSER. Browsers have crossdomain issues, not phonegap or mobile devices.

Comment: Actually... it might work in Safari if you load via `file://`, but Chrome and FF are a no go...

Comment: you can get it to work in chrome by disabling web security. in Windows Run > `chrome --disable-web-security`

In Mac OS `> sudo /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --disable-web-security --enable-geolocation`

Comment: Thanks for your reactions guys, but it still doesn't work. Still get the errorfunction running when the request is complete. I think it has something to do with the serversettings. I will take a look at it now and keep you up to date!

Answer (score 3):

Adding this to the config.xml saved me

```
<gap:plugin name="com.indigoway.cordova.whitelist.whitelistplugin" version="1.1.1" />
<access origin="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
```

I was baffled as to why any outside resource did not load, even google maps and my remote debugging tool. This saved me!

Comment: That was really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `dataType:jsonp` and set `crossDomain:true`
For cross domain ajax requests you can use jsonp. 
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Or you can append callback=? to your url.

Comment: I already tried what you suggest, but it doesn't work. Still the same problem. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: JSONP doesn't substitute a cross domain POST

Answer (score 1):

JQuery setting ：$.support.cors = true;