# How to read and display XML file from url using javascript or jquery mobile?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, xml, jquery-mobile

I'm working on creating an android application with PhoneGap. What I'm trying to do is to display the content of a xml file from the website (.php format) that I have created. Any suggestion? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to whitelist your domain like mentioned over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10177420/942368) after that you can simply use jQuery ajax

Comment: You just save my life. Thanks a lot. ^^